# MFC - Sample edit box Arabic charset

Tags: c++, character-encoding, mfc, arabic

I'm here again with a question related to MFC and Arabic Charset. 
I created a PropPage with some Sample Edit Box in order to get user's input trying this:

```
CString userName;
inputName.GetWindowText(userName);
```

where inputName is a CEdit variable associated to a single Sample Edit Box. If I put in this box a string in Western encoding everything is fine while when I try to write something with Arabic keyboard or put some Arabic text,  in userName variable I get only a string like "????"

The Solution's  Character Set is Multi-Byte. How can I get the arabic string?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties set character set to Unicode Character set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to change the character set but I get many link errors, is there another way to do that?

Comment: Done! I've create a MFC test solution using Unicode Character Set and everything works. Now I have to fix all the problems changing the charset in the main tool. Thanks!